# Why is there a "ValueError: unknown file extension" when I am trying to save images into the tif file format using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, glob, valueerror

In this code, I am trying to use a pre-loaded machine learning model and a pre-defined feature extraction function to perform image segmentation on multiple images that I have in my Train_images directory. My code runs all the way until the line "print(file)", and at that point, I am not sure what happens. This is the code I am using to go through a training set of tif image files.

```
import glob
import pickle
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

filename = "sandstone_rf_model"
loaded_model = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))

path = "images/Train_images/*.tif"
for file in glob.glob(path):
print(file)  # just stop here to see all file names 
printed
img1 = cv2.imread(file)
img = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Call the feature extraction function.
X = feature_extraction(img)
result = loaded_model.predict(X)
segmented = result.reshape((img.shape))

name = file.split("e_")
plt.imsave('images/Segmented/', segmented, cmap='jet')
```

Edit:
Previously I got a ValueError, but I changed my last line of code to the following:

`plt.imsave('images/segmented_sandstone/'+name[1], segmented, cmap='jet')`

Now I receive the following KeyError:

```
`  File 
   "/Users/zeeshanpatel/opt/anaconda3/envs/master/lib/python3.7/site- 
   packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2123, in save
   save_handler = SAVE[format.upper()]
   KeyError: 'TIF'`
```

The issue is occuring in the last line of the code, please let me know how I can format this to fix this issue.

Comment: Are you trying to name your image `images/Segmented/`? This is a folder name afaik, you missed file name.

Comment: How would I add the filename? The images/Segmented/ portion is just the file directory.

Comment: e.g. `plt.imsave('images/Segmented/my_image.png', segmented, cmap='jet')`

Comment: This code is under a for loop in which I am attempting to process multiple images, so I have edited the code above in order to process filenames specifically to my preference. However, I still receive the same KeyError as said in my post above.

Answer (score 0):

Use the tifffile library and replace the last line with  tifffile.imsave, like this

```
import tiffile
tifffile.imsave('images/segmented_sandstone/'+name[1], segmented, cmap='jet')
```